# Multiple Domains pointing to one site

Tags: seo, redirects, wordpress, dns

Newbie here so please excuse me if this has been asked in a different way.
My friend has 3 domain names lets say `example.com`, `example.net` and `example.org`.

They were not using the `.com` and `.net`. I was asked to put together something that looked like the current active site(`.org`) because it was flash and they wanted to be responsive.

I built a comparable site with `.com` and I redirected `.net` in cPanel to point to `.com`.

Now they want the `.org` site to be same as the `.com`, should I just point the `.org` DNS to my server and then redirect it to `.com` in cPanel or is it best to copy and paste all the pages and content into the `.org` and then delete content from `.com`.

I am unsure what best route is to not lose all the SEO she has on the current `.com` that is hosted elsewhere.

She doesn't want to renew with current host and hence I will host for her and make the site in WP instead flash.

Comment: Why you should point .ORG to your domain and then to .COM? It will increase routing. You can redirect .ORG to .COM directly.

Comment: @HelpingHands I expect the redirect is simply to avoid duplicate content. I assume "my server" is `.com`, where the new site has been developed.

Comment: But I want to say that if finally you decided to redirect those both domain to main domain then there is not content/anything you should put on those domain because no value of that as you redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

First, it doesn't where the actual files are, 1 is 'real' the others are aliases. To the outside world they're all alike (unless someone digs up your DNS settings, but they can't do anything with that info).

Then, I suggest you don't make two working domains. This would make you compete with yourself, which is kinda pointless. Choose one and stick to it. You can redirect ALL domains to one domain via *.htaccess* (this will go to the `.com`):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The 301 redirect preserves most pagerank (a redirect will cost you a minimal amount). Now, if you set your domains as 1 real, the remaining as aliases in you cPanel, it'll work as you want (or as it should).

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback and the promptness of the replies. Just to clarify, I replicated the .org site on the .com domain so she could compare the look. I want to preserve as much seo as possible and had origionally just thought of changing the .org over to my hosting and then doing a redirect on the .org domain name to the .com I built the sample site on. I hadnt considered the old url's on the .org (individual pages) so... Should I do the dns transfer of .org and then delete .com content and point everything to .org. Then rebuild content in .org. continued in separate post............

Comment: Cont.... If I do this, can I then go into cpanel on .org and enter the old flash page addresses in the redirect and do a 301 redirect to the new page in wordpress that is the replacement for the flash page?   Will that work?    If I copy the url in the browser of say... .org/flash1 to .org wordpress/page1 would it function?   I am real newb at this area of the web. Or would a wp plugin do the same thing as cpanel redirects?   Will entering the flash url to point to its replacement WP url work?     Sorry for the lengthy ask.

Comment: Keep the org, redirect hem all to keep seo. My examplecode will still  suffice fort that. Don't keep them both live, because [see my post]

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for SEO is to replace the existing site at `example.org`. If any URLs have changed then you need to 301 redirect old to new in order to preserve as much rank as possible. (Although if the site was previous entirely Flash then I'm not sure what old URLs you would have?)

The other domains `example.com` (where you developed the new site) and `example.org` carry no SEO value since they've never had a site on them. Save them for a rainy day!

> Now they want the .org site to be same as the .com, should I just point the .org DNS to my server and then redirect it to .com in cPanel or is it best to copy and paste all the pages and content into the .org and then delete content from .com.

Point the .org DNS to your server and make that the primary domain. There shouldn't be a need to physically copy any files.